# Accessing a file that was passed via --files to spark submit

Tags: pyspark, spark-submit

I am submitting a script to spark-submit and passing it a file using --files property. Later on I need to read it in a worker.

I don't understand what API I should use to do that. I figured I'd try just:

```
with open('myfile'):
```

but this did not work.

I am able to pass the file using the addFile mechanism but it may not be good enough for me.

This may seem like a very simple question but I did not find any comprehensive documentation on spark-submit. [The docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) sure doen't cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. I forgot to look inside spark-submit --help.
And this is what it says:

```
  --files FILES               Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                              directory of each executor. File paths of these files
                              in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).
```

Sometimes it's right under ones own nose..

Comment: we get the file path using SparkFiles.get but any reader we use FileInputStream, File, sparkSession.read().json we not file found exception.